# How get text from htmlEditor ?

Tags: extjs

I want   get text from htmlEditor ? It's possible ?

example of creating form :

```
  Ext.onReady(function(){ 
        var formPanel = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
            title: 'Редактор текста',
            width: 350,
            height:200,
            layout: 'fit',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'htmleditor',
                id:'s78d',
                     name: 'msg',
            value : 'abcd',
            id: 'myeditor'
            }],
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    });
```

Thank you.

Comment: Use the `getValue` method: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.HtmlEditor-method-getValue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decide which `id` property you actually want to use ***(remove the other)*** then try some thing like:

```js
var editorValue = Ext.getCmp('myeditor').getValue();
```

[**» fiddle**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/92s)